# How to add app icon badge in flutter android?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, android-push-notification

I am using "flutter_app_badger" for app icon badge. Its working fine with Samsung but not working in some devices like Redmi, vivo etc. How can I mange this? Do we have any option to add "badge" through notification payload like iOS?

Comment: Hey.. did you find any solution for this ??